# Sum a count(*) column

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the sum of a count(*) of 'active product lines' between 2 dates. Here is the bit I have.

I want to sum the 'Product lines active' column. I left out the other Where clauses to simplify this question.

```
SELECT mfr_id as 'Manufacturer ID', COUNT(*) AS 'Product lines Active'
FROM database.LabReport 
Where (rpt_upload_dt BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' ) 
GROUP BY mfr_id  
Order by mfr_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, the query you posted looks fine.

Comment: so what is the problem ?did you try adding sum ?

Comment: I need to be able to add all the rows of 'Product lines active' together. I've tried using sum but I am new to SQL and can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a sub query. Its one solution, might not be the best.

```
SELECT SUM(Product lines Active) AS 'sum'
FROM
    (SELECT mfr_id as 'Manufacturer ID', COUNT(*) AS 'Product lines Active'
    FROM database.LabReport 
    Where (rpt_upload_dt BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' ) 
    GROUP BY mfr_id) AS x
```

Comment: But you would be better off just using your original query and removing the group by and 'mfr_id' in the select

Comment: you're missing a `FROM` and might want to use backticks in `SUM()`. Apart from that +1

Comment: Cheers for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

As Bobby pointed out, this is the simplest solution:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Product lines Active'

FROM database.LabReport 
Where (rpt_upload_dt BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' )

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able use an aggregrate function on top of another..

Try this..

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT mfr_id as 'Manufacturer ID', COUNT(*) AS Product_lines_Active
FROM database.LabReport 
Where (rpt_upload_dt BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' ) 
GROUP BY mfr_id  
)
SELECT SUM(Product_lines_Active)
FROM CTE
```

OR
Using a aggregation directly

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Product_lines_Active
FROM database.LabReport 
Where (rpt_upload_dt BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' )
```